# How to non-italicise a subscripted mathematical word within a mathematical expression

Tags: equations, text

I have the code `$$\phi< \Arg_{\phi}(z)\leq \phi + 2\pi$$` which is meant to give a non-italicised `Arg` subscripted by phi. This shows when `arg` is lower case but now when it is capitalised. Could anyone help me fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: `\Arg` is not defined by default. I assume you're using `amsmath` then here is how to properly define it `\DeclareMathOperator\Arg{Arg}`, use `\DeclareMathOperator*` if you want ti to behave lime `\lim` regards to limits.

Comment: And next time please provide a minimal example, it is kind of the standard request around here (it lets us know what kind of class and preamble you are using as that till affect our answers)

Answer (score 3):

`\Arg` is not defined by default.

Assuming you are using `amsmath` (you should) `\Arg` can be defined via

```
\DeclareMathOperator\Arg{Arg}
```

Use `\DeclareMathOperator*` if you want limits on `\Arg` to behave lime for `\lim`.

If this is a one time use only, you can use

```
\operatorname{Arg}
```

Additionally, don't use `$$...$$` it is not LaTeX and does not comply to LaTeX configurations, se [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for more info